# If else statement inside type="text/html"

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, knockout.js, embed

How to use if else statement inside type="text/html"

I want to use `<embed>` tag for IE browsers otherwise `<object>` tag

If Internet explorer

```
 <embed data-bind="attr: { src: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 800px !important;">
```

other browsers

```
 <object data-bind="attr: { data: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  this

Create a function that checks if it is IE

Then use javascirpt to append

```
function detectIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
  if (msie > 0) {
    return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
  }

  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
  if (trident > 0) {
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
  }

  var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
  if (edge > 0) {
    return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(detectIE())

if(detectIE()){
  document.body.innerHTML=`<embed data-bind="attr: { src: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 800px !important;">`;

}else{

  document.body.innerHTML=`<object data-bind="attr: { data: data.files()[currentPage()] + '#toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0' }" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></object>`;

}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxMRxG

Comment: I want to insert inside <div class="primary-content">

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("“primary-content")[0].innerHTML